# Syntax issue with sql code selecting a specific word

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some issues with my sql statement searching my database. I need this to search specifically for the phrase entered, e.g. sky-box will return only sky-box and not sky-box-green which it is at the moment. The error I get and the code can be seen below:

Code:

```
$term = "searchTerm";
    SELECT * FROM `0530-0605` WHERE SearchTerm = [[:<:]]:searchTerm[[:>:]] UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `0606-0612` WHERE SearchTerm = [[:<:]]:searchTerm[[:>:]] UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `0613-0619` WHERE SearchTerm = [[:<:]]:searchTerm[[:>:]] UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `0620-0626` WHERE SearchTerm = [[:<:]]:searchTerm[[:>:]] UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `0627-0703` WHERE SearchTerm = [[:<:]]:searchTerm[[:>:]]

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":searchTerm", $term);
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $row) {
    $file = $row['SearchTerm'];
}
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '[[:<:]]'sky-box-not-working'[[:>:]] UNION ALL SELECT * FROM
>   `0606-0612` WHERE Se'

Not really sure how to deal with this as research showed that [[:<:]] term [[:>:]] was the way to achive what I want but it clearly isn't working

Comment: I get the feeling that this schema is horrifying.

Comment: Is this MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Mysql is what I am using

Comment: But `[[:<:]]:searchTerm[[:>:]]` is definitely not MySQL syntax. Try to use `WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm …`, while `:searchTerm` is a placeholder in a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/de/class.pdostatement.php).

Comment: Why not just use `:searchTerm`? Using PDO? Please show the code where this is being executed.

Comment: What research led you to use this: `[[:<:]]:searchTerm[[:>:]]` ?!

Comment: looking for something to make this work, pdo did not

Comment: @LewisSmith You are using PDO the correct way – but you also should learn the basics of the (My)SQL syntax.

Comment: Do you want to match something like 'green-sky-box'?  If you only want the literal 'sky-box' with nothing before or after, then why not just do a regular exact-match search?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do

Comment: `[[:<]]` is part of MySQL regular expression syntax, it needs to be used with the `REGEX` operator and it has to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what research led you to use this: `[[:<:]]:searchTerm[[:>:]]`, but it does not appear to be valid MySQL syntax.

Using PDO, you just need to add placeholders in the sql query e.g. using `:searchTerm` and then bind parameters using `bindParam()`, see full example below.

See the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Based on your code:

```
$term = "searchTerm";
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM `0530-0605` WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm
        UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM `0606-0612` WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm
        UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM `0613-0619` WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm
        UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM `0620-0626` WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm
        UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM `0627-0703` WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":searchTerm", $term);
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $row) {
    echo '<pre>'. print_r($row, true).'</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Not working, still returns results that just contain the searchTerm rather than an exact match

Comment: Well, that may be but its not returning results that follow that

Comment: @LewisSmith so you have progressed beyond a syntax error?

Comment: Yes, no longer a syntax error when using the above 2 answers, but non exact matches are being returned

Comment: @LewisSmith Examples of input and results that are not exact?

Comment: hard to explain as its hard to pinpoint which similar results getting sent back. Going to have to spend a while more debugging I think

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, based on the new code supplied by the OP:

```
$term = "searchTerm";
$query = "SELECT * FROM `0530-0605` WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `0606-0612` WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `0613-0619` WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `0620-0626` WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `0627-0703` WHERE SearchTerm = :searchTerm";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":searchTerm", $term);
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt as $row) {
    $file = $row['SearchTerm'];
}
```

Remember that when using PDO with placeholders, there is no need to escape the values (as would be necessary with mysqli): PDO handles that for you.

Comment: no, we have established that [[:<:]]:searchTerm[[:>:]] is the incorrect way of searching for the exact match of a searchTerm

Comment: Not working, still returns results that just contain the searchTerm rather than an exact match